# Issues writing data scraper

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have to make a code in order to scrape datafrom a website and then analyse them for university.
My problem is that I made this code in order to get some data for all products but when I run it it only shows a single response for each variable.
Can you help me resolve this error ?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import urllib
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
import requests


myurl='https://boutique.orange.fr/mobile/choisir-un-mobile'


Uclient=uReq(myurl)
page=Uclient.read()
Uclient.close()

pagesoup=soup(page,'html.parser')

containers=pagesoup.findAll('div',{'class':'box-prod pointer'})


container=containers[0]

produit=container.img['alt']

price=container.findAll('span',{'class':'price'})


price2=container.findAll('div',{'class':'prix-seul'})


avis=container.footer.div.a.img['alt']


file="orange.csv"
f=open(file,'w')
headers='produit,prix avec abonnement, prix seul, avis\n'
f.write(headers)


for container in containers:
    produit=container.img['alt']

    price=container.findAll('span',{'class':'price'})


    price2=container.findAll('div',{'class':'prix-seul'})


    avis=container.footer.div.a.img['alt']
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use different selectors. Separate two prices per product by index. Extract price specific info using `join` and `findall`.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://boutique.orange.fr/mobile/choisir-un-mobile'
res = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content, "lxml")
#print(len(soup.select('#resultat .box-prod.pointer')))
p = re.compile('[0-9,€]+')
altText= [item.get('alt').strip() for item in soup.select('#resultat .box-prod.pointer .lazy')]
titles = [item.text.strip().replace('\n', ' ') for item in soup.select('#resultat .box-prod.pointer .titre-produit')]
allPrices = [''.join(p.findall(item.text)) for item in soup.select('#resultat  span.price')]
aPartirPrice = allPrices[0::2]
prixSeul = allPrices[1::2]
items = list(zip(titles, altText, aPartirPrice, prixSeul))
df = pd.DataFrame(items,columns=['title', 'altText', 'aPartirPrice', 'prixSeul'])
df.to_csv(r'C:\Users\User\Desktop\Data.csv', sep=',', encoding='utf-8',index = False )
```

---

Transpose with:

```
df = df.T
```

Comment: thanks you I managed to change my code to make it work but I have one last issue : when I put it into a csv file it put all the data of each product in one column instead of doing a column for price, reviews....

Comment: try using df = df.T

Comment: DId this answer your original question?